# How to read a string representation of a binary tree back into the tree?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, tree, binary-tree

I have the following code that accepts the input as the example given in `ex` and creates a tree with the give type:

```
data QA = Leaf String | Question QA String QA

ex :: QA
ex = (Question 
       (Question (Leaf "Marie Curie") "Is she a scientist?" (Leaf "Queen Elisabeth II"))
       "Is she from Europe?"
       (Question (Leaf "Marilyn Monroe") "Is she an actress?" (Leaf "Hilary Clinton")))

showQa :: QA -> String 
showQa (Leaf x) = "(" ++ x ++ ")"
showQa (Question left x right) = "(" ++ x ++ showQa left ++ showQa right ++ ")"

instance Show QA where
  show = showQa
```

Then I convert the tree to a string using the showQa function to be able to store it in a file with the following output as string:

```
"(Is she from Europe?(Is she a scientist?(Marie Curie)(Queen Elisabeth II))(Is she an actress?(Marilyn Monroe)(Hilary Clinton)))"
```

The problem is how can I convert this string to the original tree with the original type when I read the string from the file again.

Comment: How much do you know about parsing? This is a pretty straightforward application of parsing a binary tree serialized in prefix order, which is nearly the easiest case of parsing to a recursive data structure. There aren't any big challenges, but it's worth knowing what related ideas you're comfortable with.

Comment: Though of course...  that serialization format is very awkward to reverse because it allows arbitrary parentheses in the string.  That allows ambiguous forms where multiple inputs serialize to the same output, which is... well, it's a problem for inverting the operation.

Comment: Do you care about the details of your text format ? What is wrong with `data QA = Leaf String | Question QA String QA deriving (Eq, Show, Read)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make QA an instance of show and read

```
data QA = Leaf String | Question QA String QA deriving (Show, Read)
```

You can get rid of showQa that way and just call show on QA types. Same goes for reading.

While writing to file you can

```
writeFile "[FileName].qa" (show ex)
```

"ex" should be name of a QA type, in your case it's called ex

Reading from the file you can just use readFile and read the result:

```
fileReader = do
    content <- tryIOError (readFile "[FileName].qa")
    case content of
        Left e  -> do
            return (ex) --In case of reading file goes wrong
        Right r -> do 
            return (read r)
```